# jQuery: form and ajaxcall

Tags: jquery

I would like to make an ajax call on submit.

```
<form id="editMail" action="" method="post">
    <input name="user_email" type="text" value="mail" maxlength="50" id="user_email" style="width:200px;">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit_editMail" value="Ändra">
</form>


    $('#editMail').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "misc/email/activate.php",
            data: { action: 'edit', user_email: new_usermail },
            success: function(r){
            if(typeof(r.error) != 'undefined') {
            if(r.error != ''){
            alert(r.error);
            }
                }else{
           alert('OK');
        }
      });
    });
```

But still nothing is happening, it doesnt do the ajax call but only refersh the page it's on. I tried adding onClick="return false;" to the submit button, but then nothing at all happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `false` in your handler.  Otherwise, the POST request will be started, then the default form submit will happen.  You can also use the `preventDefault` function of the event object like this:

```
$('#editMail').submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "misc/email/activate.php",
        data: { action: 'edit', user_email: new_usermail },
        success: function(r){
            if(typeof(r.error) != 'undefined') {
                if(r.error != ''){
                    alert(r.error);
                }
            }else{
                alert('OK');
            }
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit:**

Make sure your script is not running before the page has finished loading.  You may need to wrap your script in a `ready` handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#editMail').submit(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "misc/email/activate.php",
            data: { action: 'edit', user_email: new_usermail },
            success: function(r){
                if(typeof(r.error) != 'undefined') {
                    if(r.error != ''){
                        alert(r.error);
                    }
                }else{
                    alert('OK');
                }
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: it still submits, also tried with return false; and i see no ajax calls I think the script is not even running.. are the selector right?

Comment: Your selector is right; you bind `submit` event handlers to `form` elements.  Try putting an `alert` in your handler to see if the script is even running.  Your JavaScript may not be running after the page is loaded, so the selector may not be finding the form element.

Comment: Oh, and @jondavidjohn is correct that you had script errors.  My sample script has them fixed.

Comment: Thank you, modified your code instead of preventDefault (didnt work out for me), I used return false instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing bracket group for your .submit();

Also you had unnecessary ); closing your 'success' function.

Also added the needed "return false" to prevent default submit actions.

corrected:

```
$('#editMail').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "misc/email/activate.php",
        data: { action: 'edit', user_email: new_usermail },
        success: function(r){
            if(typeof(r.error) != 'undefined') {
                if(r.error != ''){
                    alert(r.error);
                }
            }else{
                alert('OK');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So I find the problem, and then you mark the answer correct of the guy that incorporates my answer in his code? weak.